# HTTP request in AccessDecisionManager is missing a header

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security

I'm trying to implement an `AccessDecisionManager` for my Spring security-protected servlet, and need to check the contents of the "Authorization" header. I have the following code, but the header (which I'm 100% sure is being sent) is coming back `null`:

```
public class MyAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {
    public void decide(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Collection<ConfigAttribute> arg2) throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {
        HttpServletRequest req = ((FilterInvocation) arg1).getHttpRequest();
        String authHeader = req.getHeader("Authorization"); //this is null
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Looking at `req` in the debugger, I can drill down into the interesting looking stuff to see the following structure:

```
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper req
|-SavedRequestAwareWrapper request
  |-DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest
    |-TreeMap headers
  |-HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper request
    |-RequestWrapper request
      |-RequestFacade request
        |-Request request
          |-Request coyoteRequest
            |-MimeHeaders headers
```

The `MimeHeaders headers` includes my "Authorization" header and has the correct value, so I know the header is making it to my server. However, the `TreeMap headers` is missing my Authorization header and (I assume) is what `getHeaders()` is looking at.

I tried adding a "foo" header on the client side to check whether the problem is specifically with "Authorization", but I'm seeing the exact same behaviour. The only headers I DO have access to are "accept-encoding", "connection", "host", and "user-agent".

The configuration is:

```
<bean id="myAccessDecisionManager" class="com.example.MyAccessDecisionManager" />
<security:http pattern="/api/**" 
    access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager" 
    entry-point-ref="myAccessDeniedHandler">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
  <security:anonymous enabled="true"/>
  <security:access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

Can anyone explain what's going on or why the header is missing? Is there any way I can get access to the value within my `decide()` function? (Or is there maybe a better way to go about making a decision based on a header value?)

Comment: do you get any error or just the header is missing?

Comment: No errors, it's just not there. I edited this into the question, but I also tried adding "foo=bar" to see if it's specifically Authorization, and saw the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to determine what the problem in `AccessDecisionManager` was or how to gain access to other request headers. Instead, I worked around the problem by disabling Spring Security on the api path:

```
<security:http pattern="/api/**" security="none"/>
```

...and using a Spring MVC interceptor instead:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/api/**"/>
    <bean class="com.example.MyInterceptor"/>
  </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I had to include the logic from both my `AccessDecisionManager` and my `AuthenticationEntryPoint` in the interceptor's `preHandle()` method, which is not ideal, but works.